# DBIO Error: Utility 'mysqldump.exe' not found in MySQL home 'MySQL Connector/Net'

Tags: mysql, windows, dbeaver

I am using dbeaver 3.6.10 and I would like to export my database (MySQL).

I select the database > right mouse click on it > tools > export database > next > start

I get the following error:

> IO Error: Utility 'mysqldump.exe' not found in MySQL home 'MySQL Connector/Net'

[image]

I do know where mysqldump.exe is located on my machine.

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe

But I am new to dbeaver and I am not completely sure where I can set the mysqldump.exe value in dbeaver in order to be able to create db dumps.

Can you anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

I've figured it out. Export database is working now.

I had to copy mysqldump.exe from

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe`

to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 6.5.4\mysqldump.exe`

Comment: https://www.andyjarrett.co.uk/2018/03/13/dbeaver-io-error-utility-mysqldump-not-found-in-client-home/ <- this will also work, edit the connection, update where you want the connection to consider `home`

Answer (score 2):

Edit the connection and be sure to select the version of mysql installed on your PC in the "Local Client" section